# Losing parameter values when using a route mapping for an Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, C#, razor and developing on IIS Express.

I have a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Item_Delete",
"Item/Delete/{id}/{a}/{b}/{c}",
new { controller = "Item", action = "Delete"}
);
```

I have an Action method:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, int a = 0, int b= 0, int c = 0)
```

When I comment out the route mapping I have :

```
http://myserver/Item/Delete/1301?a=8&b=1&c=0
```

The above querystring returns the values for a, b and c correctly ie

```
id=1301, a=8, b=1, c=0
```

However if the routing is active, I get the url converted to :

```
http://myserver/Item/Delete/1301/8/1/0
```

But I get

```
id=1301, a=0, b=0, c=0
```

in the Action Method which is really confusing me.

Perhaps I have set up my route incorrectly? It seems to be firing as I getting the url formatted correctly. The Action method just does not seem able to extract the correct parameter values from it.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT1

Cause of the issue was due to the interference of another route mapping earlier in the file:

```
routes.MapRoute("Suppliers", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{d}/{e}/{f}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new string[] { "MyApp.MVC3.ED.Controllers" });
```

The only similarities I can see are:

a) Generic {controller}.

b) Generic {action}

c) Same {id} parameter tag

d) Same number of paramers ie (d},{e},{f} , although different names. So should not interfere?

My solution for now is to put the route before the above one, but I would love to understand why the above interferes. All too much like "magic" for my comfort !!!

EDIT2

On further research it seems that if you have {controller}/{action} type patsh too early on they can cause chaos as it seems MVC will match on just the {controller} regardless of the parameters. So my solution was to use the following format for all my more specific routes:

```
MyController/MyAction/{id}..., new{controller="MyController","MyAction"}
```

Seems a bit long winded, but this seems the only predictable way to write my routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this.

write route in this way

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ItemDel", "s/{id}/{a}/{b}/{c}",
 new { controller = "Item", action = "Delete", a =    UrlParameter.Optional,b=UrlParameter.Optional,c=UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { id = @"\d+", a = @"\d+", b = @"\d+", c = @"\d+" },
  new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

and call it from controller like this

```
return RedirectToRoute("ItemDel", new
                {
                    id =1301,
                    a=8, 
                    b= 1,
                    c=0
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you need "a =    UrlParameter.Optional,b=UrlParameter.Optional,c=UrlParameter.Optional" if not optional. Also what doee @"\d+" means, regex validator for value= 0-9 ?